# Concatenate scalar with array name

Tags: perl

I am trying to concatenate a scalar with array name but not sure how to do.
Lets say we have two for loops (one nested inside other) like

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    for ($k = 0; $k <=5; $k++) {
       $array[$k] = $k;
    }
}
```

I want to create 5 arrays with names  like `@array1`, `@array2`, `@array3` etc. The numeric at end of each array represents value of `$i` when array creation in progress.
Is there a way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to create actual *variables*, for one thing, its a bad idea, and for another, there is no point. You can simply access a variable without creating or declaring it. Its a bad idea because it is what a hash does, exactly, and with none of the drawbacks.

```
my %hash;
$hash{array1} = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
```

There, now you have created an array. To access it, do:

```
print @{ $hash{array1} };
```

The hash keys (names) can be created dynamically, just like you want, so it is easy to create 5 different names and assign values to them.

```
for my $i (0 .. 5) {
    push @{ $hash{"array$i"} }, "foo";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add {} and "" to characters, when they are used as variable or array/hash name.

Try this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++){
    for ($k = 0; $k <=5; $k++){
        ${"array$k"}[$k] = $k;
    } 
}
print "array5[4] = $array5[4]
array5[5] = $array5[5]\n";
```

array5[4] =

array5[5] = 5

Comment: Doesn't work with [`strict`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html). Use hashes instead.